# what does worst case big omega(n) means?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, big-o

If Big-Omega is the lower bound then what does it mean to have a worst case time complexity of Big-Omega(n).
From the book "data structures and algorithms with python" by Michael T. Goodrich:
consider a dynamic array that doubles it size when the element reaches its capacity.
this is from the book:

> "we fully explored the append method. In the worst case, it requires
> Ω(n) time because the underlying array is resized, but it uses O(1)time in the amortized sense"

> The parameterized version, pop(k), removes the element that is at index k < n
> of a list, shifting all subsequent elements leftward to fill the gap that results from
> the removal. The efficiency of this operation is O(n−k), as the amount of shifting
> depends upon the choice of index k. Note well that this
> implies that pop(0) is the most expensive call, using Ω(n) time.

how is "Ω(n)" describes the most expensive time?

Answer (score 0):

The number inside the parenthesis is the number of operations you must do to actually carry out the operation, always expressed as a function of the number of items you are dealing with.  You never worry about just how hard those operations are, only the total number of them.

If the array is full and has to be resized you need to copy all the elements into the new array.  One operation per item in the array, thus an O(n) runtime.  However, most of the time you just do one operation for an O(1) runtime.

Common values are:

O(1):  One operation only, such as adding it to the list when the list isn't full.

O(log n):  This typically occurs when you have a binary search or the like to find your target.  Note that the base of the log isn't specified as the difference is just a constant and you always ignore constants.

O(n):  One operation per item in your dataset.  For example, unsorted search.

O(n log n):  Commonly seen in good sort routines where you have to process every item but can divide and conquer as you go.

O(n^2):  Usually encountered when you must consider every interaction of two items in your dataset and have no way to organize it.  For example a routine I wrote long ago to find near-duplicate pictures.  (Exact duplicates would be handled by making a dictionary of hashes and testing whether the hash existed and thus be O(n)--the two passes is a constant and discarded, you wouldn't say O(2n).)

O(n^3):  By the time you're getting this high you consider it very carefully.  Now you're looking at three-way interactions of items in your dataset.

Higher orders can exist but you need to consider carefully what's it's going to do.  I have shipped production code that was O(n^8) but with **very** heavy pruning of paths and even then it took 12 hours to run.  Had the nature of the data not been conductive to such pruning I wouldn't have written it at all--the code would still be running.

You will occasionally encounter even nastier stuff which needs careful consideration of whether it's going to be tolerable or not.  For large datasets they're impossible:

O(2^n):  Real world example:  Attempting to prune paths so as to retain a minimum spanning tree--I computed all possible trees and kept the cheapest.  Several experiments showed n never going above 10, I thought I was ok--until a different seed produced n = 22.  I rewrote the routine for not-always-perfect answer that was O(n^2) instead.

O(n!):  I don't know any examples.  It blows up horribly fast.

Comment: But in the first quote why it is written "in the worst case it requires Ω(n) "  and not O(n)? if Ω(n)  represents the lower bound, how can it be worst case?